# How do you compute the successive action of two angular momentum operators on a multivector in geometric algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, clifford-algebra

I'm trying to compute the action of two angular momentum operators $J_i$ on some multivector $\psi$ in geometric algebra as in page 290 of Doran & Lasenby (Geometric Algebra for Physicists).

Specifically the problem is to show that:

$$J_iJ_i\psi = 3/4\psi - 2\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla\psi + \textbf{x}\wedge\nabla(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla\psi)$$

where $J_k \psi\equiv J_{I\sigma_k}\psi = \left( (I\sigma_k)\cdot(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla) - \frac{1}{2}I\sigma_k \right)\psi I\sigma_3 $.

I have a partial solution so far:

$$\begin{align}
J_iJ_i\psi &= \left( (I\sigma_i)\cdot(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla) -\frac{1}{2}I\sigma_i\right)
\left[ \left((I\sigma_i)\cdot(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla) - \frac{1}{2}I\sigma_i\right)\psi I\sigma_3 \right] I\sigma_3   \\
 &= -(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla)_i (\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla)_i\psi 
+ I\sigma_i(I\sigma_i)\cdot(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla)\psi - \frac{1}{4}I\sigma_i I\sigma_i\psi      \\
 &= -(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla) \cdot (\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla) \psi + I\sigma_i(I\sigma_i)\cdot(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla)\psi - \frac{1}{4}I\sigma_i I\sigma_i\psi      \\
 &= \frac{3}{4}\psi + I\sigma_i (I\sigma_i)\cdot (\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla)\psi - \textbf{x}\wedge\nabla(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla\psi)
\end{align}$$

Edit:

$I\sigma_i (I\sigma_i)\cdot(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla) = \langle I\sigma_i (I\sigma_i) \cdot (\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla)\rangle_2 = \langle I\sigma_i I\sigma_i \textbf{x}\wedge\nabla \rangle_2 = -\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla$

Closer but still not correct.

Edit2: There must be an implied sum over $i$ which would explain the $3$ in $3/4\psi$.

Also, the factor of 3 is avoided in the $\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla\psi)$ term because the sum over $i$ serves to reconstitute the original $\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla$ bivectors from the projections. The geometric product $(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla)(\textbf{x}\wedge\nabla)$ only contains a scalar because the cross product is zero and the wedge product between spatial bivectors is zero.

Answer (score 0):

For the single $\nabla$ term, first rearrange using commutativity between $I$ and $\sigma_i$:

$$I^2 \sigma_i\sigma_i \cdot (\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{\nabla})\psi = -\sigma_i\sigma_i \cdot (\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{\nabla})\psi$$

Then, use the isomorphism between spacetime relative vectors $\sigma_i$ and normal grade-1 n-dimensional vectors to use the formula $e^k e_k \cdot A_r = r A_r$ (D&L 6.28/6.29) where $e_k$ is a basis vector and $A_r$ is a homogeneous grade r multivector:

$$-2\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{\nabla}\psi$$

I don't have an explanation for the wrong sign on the $\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{\nabla}(\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{\nabla}\psi)$ term.